# How can I add a new socket to a node and then make that socket connected to a property

Tags: python, node-editor

In my script, and thanks to brockmann!..  I have added a texture *(in the Texture Editor)* and also added a Texture Node *(in the compositor)*. The Texture is connected to the Texture Node and that works great. I would like to add two new sockets to change the values of one of the Nodes in the Texture editor

For example,

I have a blend Node in the Texture Editor, and I want to be able to change the colors of the blend.

[image]

I figured out how to add a socket *(which was pretty simple)* but they do not control the colors,  I am not sure how I would now connect the new sockets to the texture blend node..

I added the sockets to my Texture node like this

```
    comp_node_texture.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor', 'Color 1')
    comp_node_texture.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor', 'Color 2')
```

[image]

But I now need them to be connected?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to set node inputs values.

Say you have added texture node so that it can be accessed like so, for instance:

```
node=bpy.data.textures['Texture'].node_tree.nodes['Texture']
```

Then input slots are already created and you don't need to create the slots.

You can for instance:

```
node.inputs[0].default_value = (0,0,0,1)
node.inputs[1].default_value = (1,1,1,1)
```

An easy way to identify Python accesses is to use the tooltips:

[image]

To connect texture node output for blend node first input:

```
import bpy

tree = bpy.data.textures['Texture'].node_tree

texture_node = tree.nodes['Texture']

blend_node = tree.nodes['Blend']

tree.links.new( texture_node.outputs[0], blend_node.inputs[0] )
```

Comment: I have added Nodes in the Texture editor, one of them is a blend node.. I have also added a Texture Node in the Compositor. I would like to be able to change the colors of the blend node with the texture node.. So I have added the sockets but they are not connected to anything.

Comment: So you mean you want to connect the texture node output as input for the blend node? That's it?

Comment: sorry if I am not being clear. I just added two images to the post it may help. I have created a texture in the Texture editor and added a blend node (as in picture 1) and then in the compositor editor, I have added a texture node and connected the material (as in picture 2). I want to be able to control the colors of the blend node but on the Texture node. So I don't have to switch windows to change each color of the blend node. I have added sockets but they are useless since I am not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Oh, ok, you want to connect a texture node tree into the compositor node tree?

Comment: If that would give me control then yeah I think so..

Comment: But changing the colors (which are in the texture node tree) from the compositor? If it is it, I don't think its possible.

Comment: Yeah that's what I would like to do. I thought it would be possible..